# TFS Rollback - TF246021: An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: tfs

I am getting exception while reverting my check in.

> TF246021: An error occurred while processing your request. Technical
>   information (for administrator): SQL Server Error: 500200

The same changeset reverted by my friend without any problem :(

I am running the visual studio command prompt in Administrator mode.

Comment: [This bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693450/tfs-2010-violation-of-primary-key-constraint-pk-tbl-pendingdelta) seems to be related to your error. You could try the resolutions mentioned and/or update TFS.

Comment: @Lieven I am not sure, I am not getting any message like primary key problem. And some of my friend can do it without any issue, that is confusing me

Comment: If your friend can do it without any problem it is likely related to your workspace.  If you create a new workspace are you able to perform the rollback?

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere I didn't tried that option. I will try it and update.

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere Seems some problem with my local workspace. I created new workspace and took latest version, now it is working fine. Don't know what happened to my workspace, and MS should display some meaningful errors/warnings.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem and check my source control and see that a folder in source control marked as deleted and exists in my project.

solution: try to undelete the file/folder from source control

**as Anuraj said you can deleted the workspace and created new one**

hope it helps

Comment: I deleted the workspace and created new one, it is working fine now.